# Mule mel getting data from sfdc status

Tags: mule

Payload is in this format:

```
[[UpsertResult  created='true'
 errors='{[1][Error  fields='{[1]Payroll_Type__c,}'
 message='This payroll type is not associated to WSE's account. Please select another.'
 statusCode='FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'
]
,}'
 id='null'
 success='false'
]
]
```

I am able to get the success key as:

> message.payload.get(0).success=='false'

I want to get the value of message, errors, statusCode. tried with message.payload.message, message.payload.get(0).errors, and many cases,but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API doc](http://mulesoft.github.io/salesforce-connector/5.3.7/java/com/sforce/soap/partner/UpsertResult.html), `success` is a `boolean` field.

So you need to use:

```
message.payload[0].success == false
```

or even better if it's in a condition:

```
!message.payload[0].success
```

To access the values of the first [`Error`](http://mulesoft.github.io/salesforce-connector/5.3.7/java/com/sforce/soap/partner/Error.html) object, use:

```
message.payload[0].errors[0].message
message.payload[0].errors[0].fields
message.payload[0].errors[0].statusCode
```

Comment: I am able to get this as mentioned above. ow do I get the value for statusCode,  errors, message, created which is dsiplayed at the begning of the result.

Comment: I'm surprised the boolean to string comparison worked for you, I guess MEL  did some nice type coercion to fix the code issue. Anyway, I've extended my answer with examples of how to read the values from the first of the `Error` objects in the `errors` array.

Comment: I think it is a string value and not boolean value, success='false', (here it can be any string say 'abc'). If it is success=false then it could be a boolean comparision. is this correct?

Comment: I am getting this error: "message.payload.errors[0].statusCode" failed. Message payload is of type: ArrayList

Comment: Can you pastebin the full stack trace? Also yes for your previous comment: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/MVEL_Language_Guide#Value_coercion

Comment: solved by using: #[message.payload[0].errors[0].statusCode]. You can update your answer.